# Ошибка pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```html
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def upload_video(message):
    
    video = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)
    video.download()
```

**Я пытаюсь скачать видео которое послал пользователь, в документации написано download() но у меня выдаёт ошибку когда я пытаюсь вызвать данную функции, не понимаю какой download() они используют там, вот ссылка на документацию: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File.download**

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 75, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 660, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 722, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 682, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 26, in upload_video
    video.download()
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'download'
```

Comment: У вас неправильная документация. pyTelegramBotAPI и python-telegram-bot это две разные библиотеки для работы с API телеграма. Вот нужная вам документация https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI .

Comment: Мне с документации по pytelegrambotapi перекинуло на эту ссылку которую я вставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, после применения метода bot.get_file(message.video.file_id) видео сохраняется в переменной video. То есть, вам нужно записать эту переменную в файл.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def upload_video(message):

    video = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)
    video_name = message.video.file_name
    video_path = video.file_path
    video_as_file = bot.download_file(video_path)
    with open("ваша директория" + video_name, "wb") as videofile:
        videofile.write(video_as_file)
```

Comment: Попытался сделать так как вы написали, теперь же ошибка:    videofile.write(video)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'File', я не понимаю как это работает в документации написано про функцию download с помощью которой легко до 20мб устанавливать файлы но у меня ее нету.

Comment: @artem22nd исправил

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно ли как то получить имя файла самого а не вписывать свое?

Comment: fancier я не могу найти, откуда взять имя файла может вы сможете? если не сложно

Comment: @artem22nd исправил

Comment: Большое, спасибо вроде сам попробовал file_name указать но видимо немного ни так, ну спасибо вам